# add columns to a .csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I have an original .csv that looks like this, with 25834 rows:

[image]

I want to add some columns to this .csv, but I can't do it at the same time, so what I do is open the previous .csv and create a new one like this:

```
with open('results.csv', 'r') as read_object, \
            open('results_output.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_object:
    csv_reader = reader(read_object)
    csv_writer = writer(write_object)
    line_count = 0

    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            row.append('relative_stenosis')
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
            line_count += 1
        line_count += 1

        for image_name in os.listdir(directory_segmentation):
            if str(row[1]) == image_name:
                image = cv2.imread(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)
                row.append(
                    rel_st_calc.RelativeStenosisCalculation().calculate_relative_stenosis(image, 'green'))

                csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The code adds a column where the name of the image matches the name of one of the 150 images I have in a directory. The problem is that in the new .csv all the other rows are removed and I get a .csv of 150 rows when I want to keep the original 25834 rows. I would like to put a null value to those that don't appear, because I will need them later. How can I do that?
By now I have this:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Edit: Those are the imputs I'm using:

```
from csv import writer
from csv import reader
```

Comment: Can you add the imports needed to to use the reader and writer objects?

Comment: Move `csv_writer.writerow(row)` 8 spaces to the left (line up with `for image_name...`).

Answer (score 0):

The rows without a match disappear because you never add them to the new csv. To fix this, you're going to have to keep track of whether or not you have found an image, and then write the row with a null value in the third column if you didn't. For example:

```
third_col_value = ""
for image_name in os.listdir(directory_segmentation):
    if str(row[1]) == image_name:
        image = cv2.imread(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)
        third_col_value = rel_st_calc.RelativeStenosisCalculation().calculate_relative_stenosis(image, 'green')
        break # Already found the file, no need to finish the loop

row.append(third_col_value)
csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

It's probably a better idea to try to access that image directly though, since you already know the name of the image (in `row[1]`). This way, you aren't wasting time doing unnecessary iterations over the directory listing to find the one file named `row[1]`. To do this, replace the `for image_name in os.listdir(...):` loop with this code:

```
third_col_value = ""
image_name = row[1]
image_path = os.path.join(directory_segmentation, image_name)
if os.path.exists(image_path):
    third_col_value = rel_st_calc.RelativeStenosisCalculation().calculate_relative_stenosis(image, 'green')
row.append(third_col_value)
csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!! The only problem is that now in the first and second line I have the title. In the first line is like this: type,id,relative_stenosis and in the second line is like this: type,id,relative_stenosis,   How can I fix it? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Georgia that's because you continue executing the rest of the iteration for the first line, even though you already processed that line in the `if line_count == 0:` block. At the end of that `if` block (after the `csv_writer.writerow()` and `line_count+=1`, add `continue` to skip the rest of the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You never set a value to write to the null rows. If you add a variable that is set to True on successful completion and then check if its True after all the images have been checked you can set up a backup value.

```
with open('results.csv', 'r') as read_object, \
            open('results_output.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_object:
    csv_reader = reader(read_object)
    csv_writer = writer(write_object)
    line_count = 0

    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            row.append('relative_stenosis')
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
            line_count += 1
        line_count += 1
        
        success = False
        for image_name in os.listdir(directory_segmentation):
            if str(row[1]) == image_name:
                image = cv2.imread(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)
                row.append(
                    rel_st_calc.RelativeStenosisCalculation().calculate_relative_stenosis(image, 'green'))
                
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
                success = True
        if not success:
            row.append('NULL')
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `csv.writer` takes care of adding commas, you don't need a comma in `",NULL"`